# How can i create a list with this API Data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the runescape API for high scores.

I am getting back all of my stats from the api which is fine but im trying to figure out how choose to a specific number and print this number..

for example the number (2422)

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = ("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/index_lite.ws?player=Auz")
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

output:

```
99250,2422,387973429
88601,99,16385311
80539,99,18028072
49262,99,23912868
88752,99,27170883
67921,99,20627320
143681,96,9925614
77482,99,18671068
149914,99,13203953
237810,90,5544748
211398,90,5395751
252644,82,2629556
204600,92,7009182
119036,90,5742116
131195,90,5640895
123789,90,5847081
59633,99,14385749
98898,90,5589126
110857,86,3907880
209196,86,3709666
106292,88,4618632
112823,90,5356757
123689,84,3237408
84926,92,7156796
140533,93,7410104
10777,120,144782643
142316,80,2084250
-1,0,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
49676,1810553
-1,-1
```

I tried printing out soup[2] but i just get back a single number rather than the whole thing.

This is for a chat bot im making in discord.

Comment: You may not need BeautifulSoup at all. The data comes in rows tokenized by commas. Just split the text to get a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your API returns data in the form of *"three comma separated numbers per line"*. Therefore you may just use `r.text` in order to get the response:

```
In [14]: r.text
Out[14]: '99245,2422,387973429\n88599,99,16385311\n80538,99,18028072\n49262,99,23912868\n88753,99,27170883\n67922,99,20627320\n143675,96,9925614\n77481,99,18671068\n149905,99,13203953\n237783,90,5544748\n211377,90,5395751\n252625,82,2629556\n204586,92,7009182\n119029,90,5742116\n131186,90,5640895\n123782,90,5847081\n59632,99,14385749\n98893,90,5589126\n110850,86,3907880\n209187,86,3709666\n106286,88,4618632\n112818,90,5356757\n123683,84,3237408\n84921,92,7156796\n140528,93,7410104\n10777,120,144782643\n142309,80,2084250\n-1,0,-1\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n49672,1810553\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n122488,577\n181483,503\n-1,-1\n8478,318\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n50501,274\n101370,544\n27126,1032671\n-1,-1\n13441,15\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n56488,39\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n'
```

Then you may want to split the response into the rows:

```
In [15]: r.text.split()[0]
Out[15]: '99245,2422,387973429'
```

Splitting the row by a comma allows you to retrieve the particular value:

```
In [16]: r.text.split()[0].split(',')[1]
Out[16]: '2422'
```

You may also want to convert the response into a list of numbers, which could be easily done using list comprehensions:

```
In [17]: scores = [[int(x) for x in row.split(',')] for row in r.text.split()]

In [18]: scores[0][1]
Out[18]: 2422

In [19]: scores
Out[19]: 
[[99245, 2422, 387973429],
 [88599, 99, 16385311],
 [80538, 99, 18028072],
 [49262, 99, 23912868],
 [88753, 99, 27170883],
 [67922, 99, 20627320],
 [143675, 96, 9925614],
 [77481, 99, 18671068],
 [149905, 99, 13203953],
 [237783, 90, 5544748],
 [211377, 90, 5395751],
 [252625, 82, 2629556],
 [204586, 92, 7009182],
 [119029, 90, 5742116],
 [131186, 90, 5640895],
 [123782, 90, 5847081],
 [59632, 99, 14385749],
 [98893, 90, 5589126],
 [110850, 86, 3907880],
 [209187, 86, 3709666],
 [106286, 88, 4618632],
 [112818, 90, 5356757],
 [123683, 84, 3237408],
 [84921, 92, 7156796],
 [140528, 93, 7410104],
 [10777, 120, 144782643],
 [142309, 80, 2084250],
 [-1, 0, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [49672, 1810553],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [122488, 577],
 [181483, 503],
 [-1, -1],
 [8478, 318],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [50501, 274],
 [101370, 544],
 [27126, 1032671],
 [-1, -1],
 [13441, 15],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1],
 [56488, 39],
 [-1, -1],
 [-1, -1]]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Could you explain this line so i fully understand what is going on?

    In [16]: r.text.split()[0].split(',')[1]

Comment: This line firstly splits the response text by newlines (more precisely, by any whitespace char). The `split()` returns a list of rows and then we are retrieving the first row using the `[0]` notation. `split(',')` splits the first row by a comma and `[1]` returns the second element from the list.

Comment: Thank you so much.